# Can I disable all logs and metrics except the ContainerLogs?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I use Azure Kubernetes service, which is connected to Log Analytics Workspace.

Log Analytics Workspace collects too much data, what is quite expensive.

After googling the ways to reduce the costs I found a few recommendations, but most of them about reducing the ContainerLogs size. My case is different. I do need all ContainerLogs, but nothing else.

On the image you can see the result of running this query:

```
union withsource = tt *
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1day)
| where _IsBillable == true
| summarize BillableDataMBytes = sum(_BilledSize)/ (1000. * 1000.) by tt
| render piechart
```

[image: log analytics workspace usage]

As you can see I need only 3% of all stored data, the rest 97% I want to disable or reduce (take new values much rare). Is it possible?

Is it possible to disable/reduce at least the "Perf"?

Answer (score 0):

**Basic Logs** and **Archive Logs** options can help you. Please take a look at [**this article**](https://samcogan.com/finally-cheaper-options-for-azure-monitor-logs/).

You can find explanation below regarding Basic Logs.

> The first option is the introduction of “Basic Logs”. This sits
> alongside the current option, called “Analytics Logs”. Basic logs
> allow you to designate specific tables in your Log Analytics workspace
> as “basic”. This then means that the cost of the data ingestion is
> reduced; however, some of the features of Log Analytics are not
> available on that data. This means that you cannot configure alerts on
> this data, and the options for querying the data are limited. You also
> pay a cost for running a query against the data.

[image]

For the Archive Logs:

> The second change is adding an option for archiving logs. It is often
> necessary to keep certain logs for an extended period due to company
> or regulatory requirements. Log Analytics does support retention of
> logs for up to two years, but you pay a retention cost that is
> relatively high because the data is kept in live tables that can be
> accessed at any time.
>
> Archive logs allow you to move the data into an offline state where it
> cannot be accessed directly but is significantly cheaper. Archive data
> is charged at $0.025 per GB per month, compared to $0.12 per GB per
> month for standard data retention. If you need to access the archive
> data, you pay an additional fee for either querying the archive or
> restoring it to active tables. This costs $0.007 per GB of data
> scanned for querying or $0.123 per GB per day of data restored (so
> effectively the same as standard data retention.). These prices were
> correct at the time of publishing, please check the Azure Monitor
> pricing page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, a day before your answer I tested it and had an error with the message similar to "Not permitted operation for this table". 

Now I am thinking about setting up my own logs and metrics monitoring tools inside the cluster.